# Cisco VLAN Taking up Entire Subnet

Tags: cisco, switch

I have a default vlan 1 that has an IP configuration of 10.20.11.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

I have an AP 10.20.11.55 that I want to place on its own VLAN because I intend to make this AP guest-accessible. I would want to segregate traffic on this AP from the rest of my network.

I am able to add the AP to the VLAN, but it gets no internet because IP isn't configured. When I try to give the VLAN interface its own IP such as "10.20.11.223 255.255.255.0" (that's not taken) it says it overlaps. What's the solution to giving the VLAN its own IP so it may give guests access to internet?

Answer (score 0):

For routing to work, each IP subnet (matching a VLAN) needs to use a unique, non-overlapping prefix. 10.20.11.223 is part of 10.20.11.0/24, the subnet in VLAN 1, so you can't use that in another VLAN. E.g. any IP from 10.20.12.0/24 would work.

Also make sure that there's DHCP server on that subnet/VLAN if attaching hosts expect dynamic configuration, and add a static route to the new subnet on your main router as well.